# Linux: How can I grep text from string to string that same contents?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a paragraph follow as (name file is index.txt):

```
TCP  192.168.56.224:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.112:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.113:80            Route   1      0          0
TCP  192.168.56.225:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.109:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.110:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.111:80            Route   1      0          0
TCP  192.168.56.226:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.114:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.115:80            Route   1      0          0
TCP  192.168.56.227:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.116:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.117:80            Route   1      0          0
TCP  192.168.56.228:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.118:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.119:80            Route   1      0          0
UDP  192.168.56.224:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.112:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.113:80            Route   1      0          0
UDP  192.168.56.225:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.109:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.110:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.111:80            Route   1      0          0
UDP  192.168.56.226:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.114:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.115:80            Route   1      0          0
UDP  192.168.56.227:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.116:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.117:80            Route   1      0          0
UDP  192.168.56.228:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.118:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.119:80            Route   1      0          0
```

So, I only wanna extract a paragraph from above paragraph:

```
TCP  192.168.56.225:80 rr
      -> 192.168.56.109:80            Route   1      0          0
      -> 192.168.56.110:80            Route   1      0          0
      -> 192.168.56.111:80            Route   1      0          0
```

I using bash shell.

@oliv: Yes. But, when I run with command:

```
#sudo ipvsadm -Ln | grep 192.168.56.*:80 | awk -v RS='TCP  ' -F'[ :]+' '$1=="192.168.56.228"{print RT,$0}'
```

Then the result show is:

```
TCP  192.168.56.228:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.118:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.119:80            Route   1      0          0
UDP  192.168.56.224:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.112:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.113:80            Route   1      0          0
UDP  192.168.56.225:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.109:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.110:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.111:80            Route   1      0          0
UDP  192.168.56.226:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.114:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.115:80            Route   1      0          0
UDP  192.168.56.227:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.116:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.117:80            Route   1      0          0
UDP  192.168.56.228:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.118:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.119:80            Route   1      0          0
```

I just want to retrieve information in the TCP block when I enter parameter is 192.168.56.228 or 192.168.56.225.

@RavinderSingh13
When I run with your command:

Case 1:

```
#cat ipvsadm.txt | grep 192.168.*.*:80 | awk '/^TCP/{flag=""} /^TCP  192.168.56.226:80 rr/||/^TCP  192.168.56.227:80 rr/{flag=1} flag'
```

This is result:

```
TCP  192.168.56.226:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.114:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.115:80            Route   1      0          0
TCP  192.168.56.227:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.116:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.117:80            Route   1      0          0
```

Case 2:

```
#cat ipvsadm.txt | grep 192.168.*.*:80 | awk '/^TCP/{flag=""} /^TCP  192.168.56.228 :80 rr/||/^TCP  192.168.56.228:80 rr/{flag=1} flag'
```

This is results:

```
TCP  192.168.56.228:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.118:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.119:80            Route   1      0          0
UDP  192.168.56.224:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.112:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.113:80            Route   1      0          0
UDP  192.168.56.225:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.109:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.110:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.111:80            Route   1      0          0
UDP  192.168.56.226:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.114:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.115:80            Route   1      0          0
UDP  192.168.56.227:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.116:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.117:80            Route   1      0          0
UDP  192.168.56.228:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.118:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.119:80            Route   1      0          0
```

When I run with case 2, the result is not what I expected.
I only want to extract from index.txt file:

```
TCP  192.168.56.228:80 rr
      -> 192.168.56.118:80            Route   1      0          0
      -> 192.168.56.119:80            Route   1      0          0
```

I just want to extract the TCP 192.168.56.228:80 fragment when input from keyboard. And do not want to extract the UDP segment below.
Thanks.

Comment: are you looking for something like `grep -z "TCP[^(TCP)]*" yourfile.txt`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried? Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short order unpaid programming staff. Review [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand.
I only want to extract as:

TCP  192.168.56.225:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.109:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.110:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.111:80            Route   1      0          0

Comment: @donald.sys, please show your efforts what you have put to solve this problem is what ghoti sir meant here, as we all are here to learn.

Comment: If every block is three lines, then a simple `grep` command will work; something like (untested) `grep -A2 "^TCP  *${1//./\\.}:"`.

Comment: @TobySpeight: The block is not limit lines. So, I cannot use grep with -A option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Adding solution as OP changed question a bit now.

```
awk ''/^TCP/||/^UDP/{flag=""} /^TCP  first_ip:80 rr/||/^TCP  second_ip:80 rr/{flag=1} flag' Input_file
```

---

Could you please try following `awk` if this helps you.

```
awk '/^TCP/||/^UDP/{flag=""} /^TCP  your_ip:80 rr/{flag=1} flag' Input_file
```

replace `your_ip` with the one which you want to print in my above code too.

Comment: I updated reply above.
I just want to extract the TCP 192.168.56.228:80 fragment when input from keyboard. And do not want to extract the UDP segment below.

Comment: I haved test 2 case your solution and updated the result above question. Can you help me?

Comment: Yes, I'm having problems when I want to extract the TCP fragment of 192.168.56.228:80. I have used your solution but it will show both TCP results 192.168.56.228:80 and UDP.

Can you copy my index.txt content and test it on your environment?

Comment: awk '/^TCP/||/^UDP/{flag=""} /^TCP  192.168.56.228:80 rr/{flag=1} flag'. This is solution. Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk:

```
awk -v RS='TCP  ' -F'[ :]+' '$1=="192.168.56.225"{print RT,$0}' file
```

Setting `RS` allows to parse a multiline record, and by setting the field separator (with `-F`), the ip can be looked up.

Alternatively you can use this:

```
awk -v RS='(TC|UD)P  ' -F'[ :]+' '$1=="192.168.56.225" && RT~/TCP/{print RT,$0}' file
```

Comment: Thanks, but I new update contents. Can you help me again?

Comment: @donald.sys The command still works. What is your problem with it?

Comment: Yes, I'm having problems when I want to extract the TCP fragment of 192.168.56.228:80. I have used your solution but it will show both TCP results 192.168.56.228:80 and UDP. Can you copy my index.txt content and test it on your environment?